# Species Identification: Spider

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I usually would search for myself, but I need to be **super** sure about the identification because I need to know if I need to get an exterminator in here or not. (I think it might be a giant house spider, but don't let me influence your analysis.)

So I live in the northern part of Ireland (About 40 minutes from Derry Northern Ireland over in County Donegal) and I went to my bathroom to a VERY fun surprise this morning. It was this wonderful spider in my bathroom. For reference, the lip of the glasses it is depicted in are 8 - 8.5 cm in diameter.

The missing leg was not my fault either, I was very gentle with the spider and released it outside post photo-shoot. (**Warning:** these are macro shots of the said spider)

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

More high resolution photos available on my Flickr ([SolarLunix](https://www.flickr.com/photos/125596053@N08)).

Comment: "I live in the northern part of Ireland and I went to my bathroom" - assuming the bathroom is within walking distance of the house, its the northern region of Ireland ;P

Comment: An image from the top in good light would help, maybe a wolf spider

Comment: @rg255 That was the best I could do given the circumstances and the need to get it outside before my hubby woke up and freaked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images in the question are of a giant house spider, as hypothesized in the question. (`Eratigena duellica`/`atrica`/`saeva`). These (along with the hobo spider, `Eratigena agrestis`) do not have any banding or annulations in their legs (dark/light stripes/rings).

The spider in the other answer of `Tegenaria domestica` do (always) exhibit leg banding. So, it is not the spider in question.

Both `Eratigena` and `Tegenaria` are in the funnel weaver family.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a [house spider (*Tegenaria domestica*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_domestica)

[image]

Comment: I just love these to-the-point answers +1

Comment: This is close, but not quite correct